# Getting the Control inside a table

Tags: javascript, asp.net, controls, findcontrol

I'm trying to get the control which is inside of a cell table; in my table I have different controls, labels, checkboxes, etc.

I basically need to get the control which is used in that table

```
var x = document.getElementById('myTable').rows[0].cells;
alert(x[0].innerText);
//alert(x[3].innerHTML);

if (x.Control == checkbox) {

    x.checked = true;
}
```

This will be in a loop but for now I just need to be able to check the checkbox by grabbing the control and setting that control to true

Any hints/help would be great

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't really understand what you exactly need is it

```
document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true;
```

here checkbox is the id of a particular checkbox

Comment: I don't know what the ID of my checkbox will be as their dynamically created, I just either need to be able to get the control or get the ID

Answer (score 0):

I would put a unique id on the form element instead and use that to grab it. In this way you can change the structure in the future. Example: perhaps you no longer want to use a table grid, but a grid of divs.

When you use innerHTML you will might also grab textnodes and other things you put in the cell.

An alternative - if you really want to find a specific cell in a table - is to give each cell a unique id on the form "cell-4-5" where 4 is the row and 5 is the column.

[EDIT]

If you want to have the cell contents returned as a DOM-object then childNodes can be used:

```
var x = document.getElementById('myTable').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes
```

If you want to have the cell contents returned as a string then innerHTML can be used:

```
var x = document.getElementById('myTable').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML
```

To check if the checkbox is checked you need to keep it as a DOM element and thus use the first version.

Comment: I just need to get the control type from the cell, I don't want to change it from a table.